# Does anyone know when ember-data will be ready? Or is there are other solutions for REST API communication?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a pure REST rails backend and I'm working on the client side using Ember.JS I understand that ember-data is used for REST communications but I see it's not even in production does anyone know when it will be ready?

Or if there is a better solution that can be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be fair, Ember.js itself hasn't actually reached a stable 1.0 version yet. From personal experience, I've only ever used the ember-latest.js because their tagged versions are usually so far behind the latest version, and there are too many things missing for me in their 1.0 pre tag. Even the API documentation on emberjs.com is for ember-latest.js, and the 1.0 pre API docs have been archived.

With that being said, as long as you are willing to dig through the new API documentation which is now quite nice, writing in Ember has been a fairly stable and consistent experience for me all summer. Ember Data has also been pretty good, but you have to look into the source code for most of the documentation.

Ember Data has by far the best REST adapter for Ember that I know of, especially because it is built specifically for rails.  Look into [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers). It almost makes building your API in rails a trivial task. It works perfectly fine for hasOne, hasMany and belongsTo once you understand the conventions explained in the readme for Ember Data. Many-to-many relationships should probably be decomposed into two hasMany relationships with a model in between.

In terms of when it will be ready, they intend to merge ember-data into Ember.js before the final 1.0 release. ([source](http://emberjs.com/blog/2012/08/03/ember-1-0-prerelease/#toc_known-issues)) They have both been stable enough for me though, and quite a number of companies who have already deployed ember apps. Backbone.js is at 0.9.2 and tons of people have put their trust in that, even though backbone doesn't really have something like ember-data.

Comment: Thanks I was a bit worried as ember-data on github has a failed status. Also were do you get ember-latest.js? github is giving the pre 1.0 tag or branch.

Comment: These testing statuses can be taken lightly IMHO. Tests are only as good as when you wrote them. They don't seem to commit to ember-data as often as ember.js, so they probably just haven't gotten around to adjusting some tests that failed on a major change.

Comment: https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js and http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.js - you can find these when you click on the downloads tab in github (next to tags)

Comment: As of 9/15/2012, the relationship-improvements branch of ember-data is the most up-to-date and is use in production by at least a couple of teams, including mine.

Comment: Make sure to read this file before using that branch: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/relationship-improvements/BREAKING_CHANGES.md

Comment: Thanks, will check it out but I'm also looking at Angular.JS which seems to be more production ready.

Was looking at ThorneJS and I understand that version pre 1.0 will have breaking changes.